# Install SASS using gem on Windows 8

Tags: rubygems, sass, ruby-2.0

I am trying to install SASS on Windows 8 x64, but still getting errors, even when my firewall is switched off.

**I make this command:**

```
C:\Ruby200-x64\bin>gem install sass
(or C:\Ruby200-x64\bin>ruby -S gem install sass)
```

**I get this response:**

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sass' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from http://rubygems.org/ - Errno::EACCES: Per
mission denied - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem solved**

Even if Norton Security was disabled, Windows firewall was disabled, still was getting this error. After uninstalling Norton Security it worked.

Answer (score 9):

This is work for me.   Try this...

**gem source -a http://rubygems.org/**

answer **y** to the question "Do you want to add this insecure source?"

then you can use command...

**gem install sass**

- good luck, guy!

Answer (score 0):

Try running your console with administrative privileges.

Comment: Do you just log in as an admin and launch the console via left mouse click? Or you use the "Run as administrator" option of the right click menu?